# Numerical Analysis: Given a function and successive derivatives at one point, what's the value of the function at another point?

Tags: functions, derivatives, numerical-methods

Example of an exercise I'm trying to solve: Find the value of $f ( 4)$ given that $f (6 )=350 , f ' (6 )=87 , f'' (6 )=30 , f ''' (6 )=4$ and all
other higher derivatives of $f (x) at x=6$ are zero.

I don't know how to proceed.

Comment: Is it given *perhaps* the function is a polynomial?

Comment: Are there any other conditions on $f$?

Comment: No, that's the full question.

Comment: Well unless you have something more you can't answer - the function could be nice between $x=5$ and $x=7$ and have all these lovely derivatives at $6$ and might not even be continuous at $x=4$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

More hypothesis are required. If f is analytic, then
$$f(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty{f^{(n)}(6)\over n!}(x-6)^n=\sum_{n=0}^3{f^{(n)}(6)\over n!}(x-6)^n.$$
But if $f$ isn't analytic (even if is $C^\infty$) the values of the function and all the derivatives in one point give *zero* information about the function in other point.

Comment: I think it is analytic, hence your answer is correct.

Comment: Then. you can accep it.

Answer (score 0):

Write the Taylor series:  $f(4)=f(6)+(4-6)f'(6)+\frac 12(4-6)^2f''(6)+\dots$  No guarantees of accuracy, but if the function is analytic you will get it exactly.

Comment: That's exactly what I attempted to right now, and I think that's the right way given that the question is asked in the Taylor Series chapter. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @EddieEC - note that you are then assuming that the function has a Taylor series i.e. that the remainder in the expansion goes to zero.